# Kotlin JetPack Compose, changing color of dynamic composed buttons

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

So I have this code:

```
@Composable
fun Botones(strings: MutableMap<String, Color>) {

    Column{
        strings.forEach { color ->
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    // Update the button color
                    if (color.value == Color.Red) {
                        color to Color.Blue
                    } else if (colo.value == Color.Blue) {
                        color to Color.Green
                    } else {
                        color to Color.Red
                    }
                },
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = color.value)
            ) {
                // Place the string in the buton, set font color to white
                Text(colorsito.key, color = Color.White)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Initially, all colors should be red, and every time a button is clicked, it should change its color, while the other buttons should remain the same. I don't necesarely need to use a mutable map, what I want is, for every string, make a red button, that when clicked, changes it color depending on which color it had before.
Problem is I can't get it to work because apparently it doesn't recompose. I tried using remember, but it doesn't detect when a value of a mutable map changes, and I sincerely don't know how to get it to work. Help would be much appreciated, I've been googlin' for a while with 0 results, and not even chatGPT was able to get it to work correctly.

EDIT: So magically Copilot suggested this, and it works, but I would very much appreciate if someone could explain why:

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable(items: List<String>) {
    var itemsio by remember { mutableStateOf(items) }
    LazyColumn {
        items(itemsio.size) { index ->
            var item = itemsio[index]
            var color by remember { mutableStateOf(Color.Red) }
            Text(item, modifier = Modifier.background(color).clickable(
                    interactionSource = remember {MutableInteractionSource()},
                    indication = null
                ) {
                    if (color == Color.Red) {
                        color = Color.Blue
                    } else if (color == Color.Blue) {
                        color = Color.Green
                    } else {
                        color = Color.Red
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
```

interactionSource and indication makes it work? but why

Comment: It's the color that is remembered made it work because it will keep its value on every recomposition

Answer (score 4):

It looks like CoPilot or chatGPT need some time to take our jobs

Code suggested by CoPilot actually doesn't work, when you scroll up or down it resets back to **Red** because of how `LazyList` works.

When you scroll an item out of Viewport it exits composition, when that item is visible again it enters composition with block inside remember is calculated with default value.

I made a small cosmetic change to display why that code doesn't work also it contains redundant code either.

[image]

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable(items: List<String>) {
    
    // CoPilot why var and why do you need this list here if it's a param? And if list changes it won't be recomposed with new list either
    var itemsio by remember { mutableStateOf(items) }
    LazyColumn(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp)
    ) {
        items(itemsio.size) { index ->
            var item = itemsio[index]
            var color by remember { mutableStateOf(Color.Red) }

            Text(item,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(color)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .clickable(
                        interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
                        indication = null
                    ) {
                        if (color == Color.Red) {
                            color = Color.Blue
                        } else if (color == Color.Blue) {
                            color = Color.Green
                        } else {
                            color = Color.Red
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(10.dp)
            )
        }

    }
}
```

This can be achieved in various ways, i will post only 2.

#### Using rememberSaveable

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable(items: List<String>) {

    LazyColumn(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp)
    ) {
        items(items) { item ->
            var colorId by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(0) }

            val color = when (colorId) {
                1 -> {
                    Color.Blue
                }
                2 -> {
                    Color.Green
                }
                else -> {
                    Color.Red
                }
            }

            Text(item,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(color)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .clickable {
                        colorId = (colorId + 1) % 3
                    }
                    .padding(10.dp)
            )
        }

    }
}
```

#### Using a model and ViewModel/Presenter

You can create a model that contains color or select id for selection status such as 0 for not selected, 1 for red and so on or enum. Then inside a ViewModel, presenter or any class that your choosing should handle color changes while keeping models updated with latest color.

Result

[image]

[In this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74673860/5457853) i change selected status but it can easily be applied. I used int to keep Compose class Color out of ViewModel

```
@Immutable
data class MyItem(val text: String, val colorId: Int = 0)
```

ViewModel implementation

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val myItems = mutableStateListOf<MyItem>()
        .apply {
            repeat(20) {
                add(MyItem(text = "Row $it"))
            }
        }

    fun items() = myItems


    fun toggleSelection(index: Int) {

        val item = myItems[index]
        val newColorId = (item.colorId + 1) % 3
        myItems[index] = item.copy(colorId = newColorId)

    }
}
```

Usage

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable(viewModel: MyViewModel) {
    LazyColumn(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp)
    ) {


        itemsIndexed(items = viewModel.items()) { index: Int, item: MyItem ->

            val color = when (item.colorId) {
                1 -> {
                    Color.Blue
                }
                2 -> {
                    Color.Green
                }
                else -> {
                    Color.Red
                }
            }

            Text(text = item.text,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(color)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .clickable {
                        viewModel.toggleSelection(index)
                    }
                    .padding(10.dp)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

#### Using SnapshotStateMap

Other alternative is using `SnapshotStateMap` which contains indices and color as Int or as compose Color and update index with next color

```
val map: SnapshotStateMap<Int, Int> = remember {
    mutableStateMapOf()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `remember` in `forEach` block

```
Column {
    strings.forEach { color ->
        var _color by remember { mutableStateOf(color.value) }
        Button(
            onClick = {
                _color = when (_color) {
                    Color.Red -> Color.Green
                    Color.Green -> Color.Blue
                    Color.Blue -> Color.Red
                    else -> Color.Red
                }
            },
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(containerColor = _color)
        ) {
            Text(color.key, color = Color.White)
        }
    }
}
```