# Animatable.animateTo triggered every time in Canvas Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

I have used Animatable.animateTo for animating like below,

```
val percentageAnimate = remember { Animatable(0.001f) }
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    percentageAnimate.animateTo(percentage)
}
```

with percentageAnimate.value I will be drawing my PieChart in the Canvas Composable.

I need the animation only during the first composition.

When I used the above said item in the LazyVerticalGrid, the animation gets triggered everytime when the list item got recycled and added.

Comment: If you need it only to animate on composition, you should use Unit, true, false or anything that won't change as key of LaunchedEffect

Comment: Yes I have tried using **Unit** too. But it behaves incorrectly...

Comment: Everytime the Item is recycled, the animation gets triggered.

Comment: So it works as intended. You either need to store your key with rememberSavable or inside a ViewModel because LazyList composes items in viewport and one item that about to enter viewport which is visible area

Comment: You can use this answer as reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/74793900/5457853

Comment: Yes, understood the issue. Thanks. Used a Boolean flag with **rememberSaveable**  and controlled the value of **percentageAnimate**.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have set `percentageAnimate` as key, the key is changed (and its internal state) when you call `.animateTo()` and that leads to relaunching the coroutine in `LaunchEffect`. If you want to start the animation only once you need to have constant key.

```
val percentageAnimate = remember { mutableStateOf(Animatable(0.001f)) }
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    percentageAnimate.value.animateTo(percentage)
}
```

Then use it in the draw phase `percentageAnimate.value`

Comment: Still it behaves in the same way.